# How to use System.arraycopy?

Tags: java

I want to read from a txt file and I am using `System.arraycopy` to copy
`parts[]` to `scores[]`.

I know that `scores` must be a `String` in order to work. My 
constructor has to be an `int[]` array for `scores`. So `scores` is an `int[]`. Is there any solution?

```
private void processLine(String line) {

String mygoden1 = "";
//String mygoden2 = "";

try {
    String parts [] = line.split(",");

    mygoden1= parts[0];

    Name name = new Name(parts[1]);

    int gN1=Integer.parseInt(mygoden1);

    String gL= parts[3];
    //gL = gL.trim();

    String gC = parts[4];
    gC=gC.trim();

    int scoresLength = parts.length-4;
    String scores[]=new String[scoresLength];       

    System.arraycopy(parts,4,scores, 0, scoresLength);

    Gamer g1 = new Gamer(gN1 ,name,scores, gL, gC);

    this.add(g1);
}
```

This is my constructor:

```
public class Gamer {

private int gnumb;            //The Gamers Number  g -> is for gamer
private Name gamerName;

private String glevel;
private String gCountry;
private static final int SCORES_1 =5;
private int  [] scores;

//}

public Gamer(int gN ,Name name, int gS[], String gL , String gC)
{
    gnumb = gN;
    gamerName=name;
    scores =  new int [SCORES_1];
    scores=gS;
    glevel =gL;
    gCountry =gC;   
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match you question. I don't see anything wrong with the code. If the problem is in your constructor, please show us that code, rather than some other bit of code which is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace

```
String scores[]=new String[scoresLength];       

System.arraycopy(parts,4,scores, 0, scoresLength);
```

with

```
int[] scores = new int[scoresLength];
for(int i = 0; i < scoresLength; i++)
   scores[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i + 4]);
```

Comment: That was very helpfull,but the problem is that when i want to read from a txt file the score which is 5 digits like(2 4 5 1 8) and store it to scores[] (from 0 to 4) it only stores the hole number as an int and not scores[0]=2 ,scores[1]=4,scores[2]=5 etc...  it stores it as scores[0]=24518......any sugestions?

Comment: If you want convert digits, you can do `scores[i] = parts[4].charAt(i) - '0'`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `System.arraycopy` when you need to transform data. Iterate over `parts` and `parseInt()` each element, then store it in `scores`.

Comment: In this code `parts` and `scores` are both `String[]` so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Part of the problem is poor communication. As I understand the question, the OP wants `scores` to be an `int[]`, not a `String[]`. Perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I did what you said but it stil gives me an converison error for the Name:name.Is it posible to parseInt each ellement even if this is a String or an object like name?

Comment: @James P You can parseInt() a string containing an integer. Nothing else. You seem to be confusing copying with conversion.